# Why does bootstrap row has a margin of -15?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

The row as a `margin:-15` so it is larget than its container(-fluid).

[image: This is the container]
[image: This is the row !]

Is there a reason for it ?
**How to cut it out (properly) ?**

Comment: If you downvote please give a hint on the reason so I can close the question if absurd, or improve it if not good enough.

Comment: I did not downvote it. I only referenced the dup question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, there is a `15px` space between 2 columns in bootstrap. And when implementing it, bootstrap's creator uses CSS properties called `padding-left` and `padding-right` to set the left and right padding of the column so that the requirement could be full-filled.

> *Reference: access this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) and search for **Gutter Width***

But there is a problem. The first column only needs `padding-right` and the last column only needs `padding-left`.

To solve that problem, bootstrap's creator comes up with a solution in which they sets the left and right margin of the `row` to be `-15px` (negative padding is not supported in CSS).

I usually create another CSS class that adjust the padding / margin then append it after the `row` class.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment !